# TSQL - Random winner for multiple locations based on weight

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, random

Our company does a drawing every month for "customer of the month". The drawing is basically a weighted drawing based on how much the customer spent that month.

Currently I am getting the customer name and their amount of points and running it through an Excel randomizer I found online. This becomes cumbersome doing it individually for 40+ locations every month.

I am going to appologize becuase I have seen some other questions about this but i just cant wrap my head around writing the TSQL to choose the random weighted winner.

Obvisously it would be nice if a single command could output me a random winner for each location, but im having difficulty finding out where to start and ensuring that its choosing the weighted winner correctly.

[image: Base Query with Results:]

Desired results would just be a list of winners, one per location.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, what do "locations" have to do with "customer of the month"?

Comment: I added a picture of my base query and the results. Location is important because there would be 1 winner per location.

Comment: . . You should add the query as text.

Comment: [random = 4](https://www.xkcd.com/221/). :-)

Comment: Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum for this type of problem.  Here is a relatively simple implementation:

```
select t.*
from (select locationId, customerId, sum(sales) as sumSales,
             sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by locationId) as total_sales,
             (sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by locationId order by newid()) * 1.0 / sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by locationId)) as cumulative_ratio
      from t
      where salesdate between ? and ?  -- whatever your range
      group by locationId, customerId
     ) t
where 0.5 >= cumulative_ratio - sumSales * 1.0 / total_sales and
      0.5 < cumulative_ratio;
```

You can see what this is doing.  Assume you have 4 customers at a location:

```
l    c    s
1    A    1
1    B    2
1    C    3
1    D    4
```

Then this augments the data as:

```
l    c    s    total_sales  cumulative ratio
1    A    1        10             0.1    
1    B    2        10             0.3 
1    C    3        10             0.7
1    D    4        10             1.0
```

The final `WHERE` chooses the row where 0.5 is between the cumulative ratio and the preceding value.  It does this by subtracting out the current rows data from the ratio.

This example shows the customers ordered alphabetically.  However, the query orders them randomly.  The 0.5 is totally, totally arbitrary.  Any value will do because the randomness is already built into the cumulative ratio.

EDIT:

Alas, this doesn't work on SQL Server 2008.  We can fix that using `apply`, although the code is even less efficient:

```
with sales as (
      select locationId, customerId, sum(sales) as sumSales, newid() as random
      from t
      where salesdate between ? and ?  -- whatever your range
      group by locationId, customerId
     )
select t.*
from (select locationId, customerId, sum(sales) as sumSales,
             ss.runningsumsales,
             sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by locationId) as totalsales
      from sales s cross apply
           (select sum(s2.sumsales) as runningsumsales
            from sales s2
            where s2.locationId = s.locationId and s2.random <= s.random
           ) ss
      where salesdate between ? and ?  -- whatever your range
      group by locationId, customerId
     ) t
where 0.5 >= (runningsumsales - sumSales) * 1.0 / total_sales and
      0.5 < runningsumsales / total_sales;
```